# Are there cron-expressions to run a script every ninth minute?

Tags: cron, sh

I'd like to run a bash command every 9th minute and every 70th minute.

`man -S 5 crontab` says:

> Steps are also permitted after an  asterisk,  so  if  you want to say "every two hours", just use "*/2".

I ran the command

```
echo "Cron-job runs. ($(date))" >> crontest.log
```

with the cron expression

```
*/9 * * * *
```

which gave me

```
Cron-job runs. (We 25. Mar 13:27:01 CET 2015)
Cron-job runs. (We 25. Mar 13:36:01 CET 2015)
Cron-job runs. (We 25. Mar 13:45:01 CET 2015)
Cron-job runs. (We 25. Mar 13:54:01 CET 2015)
Cron-job runs. (We 25. Mar 14:00:01 CET 2015)
Cron-job runs. (We 25. Mar 14:09:01 CET 2015)
Cron-job runs. (We 25. Mar 14:18:01 CET 2015)
```

It seems, that `*/9` means "every minute that can be divided by nine without remainder" (this includes zero!) instead of "every ninth minute".

Are there cron-expressions to define intervals?

Answer (score 1):

Or you could run your script every minute, and the script can check if it's the right time to run.

untested

```
#!/bin/bash
minute_of_the_epoch=$(( $(date +%s) / 60 ))
(( minute_of_the_epoch % 9 != 0 )) && exit

# rest of script ...
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no facility for this specific use case.  You could create a complex crontab which lists all the combinations;

```
0-54/9 0-21/3 * * * crontest
3-57/9 1-22/3 * * * crontest
6-51/9 2-23/3 * * * crontest
```

(This complex syntax is an extension, but since you were asking about `*/9` which is a similar extension, you should be able to use the above as well.  See an earlier version of this answer for the full-hand syntax, which however I incorrectly identified as extended in my original answer.)

For execution every 70 minutes, a similar table would be a lot more complex, because 70 is not evenly divisible by 1440 (24*60).  You end up with a periodicity over multiple days, so the table gets so complex as to beg for alternative solutions.

... One of which would be to use a self-scheduling `at` job:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$0" "$@" | at now + 70 minutes
:
# the rest of your crontest script here
```

You need to start this one manually the first time, but it will keep scheduling new jobs after that.  (If your server is down for an extended period of time, you may need to restart it; but the job should survive the occasional quick reboot just fine.)